# Print spiral matrix of m x n size with O(1) space complexity numbered from 1 to mn

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matrix, data-structures

I want to print a spiral matrix with m x n size numbered from 1 to m*n. This should be achieved with O(1) storage that is print without storing. Is it possible to achieve?
I did when matrix is nxn but unable to do with m*n.

Example: m=4 n=3

Output:

```
1  2  3
10 11 4
9  12 5
8  7  6
```

Comment: For all places of `n` in your code of n x n matrix, check where all you have to put `m`.

Comment: Can you share your attempt for nxn?

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying for **O(1)** space complexity, the following C code will do it, although the time complexity is invariably worse as a result of the trade-off.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
//Simulates filling the array in spiral fashion
//and finds the index we are currently in, and returns it.
int findVal(int x,int y,int m,int n)
{
    int i,j,val=1,start=0,end=n,top=0,bottom=m;
    while(val<=m*n)
    {
        for(i=start;i<end;i++)
        {
            if(top==x&&i==y)
            return val;
            val++;
        }
        for(i=top+1;i<bottom;i++)
        {
            if(i==x&&y==end-1)
            return val;
            val++;
        }
        for(i=end-2;i>=start;i--)
        {
            if(x==bottom-1&&y==i)
            return val;
            val++;
        }
        for(i=bottom-2;i>=top+1;i--)
        {
            if(x==i&&y==start)
            return val;
            val++;
        }
        start++;
        end--;
        top++;
        bottom--;
    }
    return -1;
}
int main()
{
    int m=4,n=3,i,j;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",findVal(i,j,m,n));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps you out. Cheers :)